# Getting error when cloning my bitbucket repo for the first time

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I've added my public ssh key to my bitbucket acct and did this this:

```
stefan@stefan-Desktop:~/Desktop/jobsrc$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:stremio/wifi-setup.git
Cloning into 'wifi-setup'...
repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the requested repository.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm not sure what a deployment key is, except I'm pretty sure I don't want or need one.

Any ideas?

I've found [this page](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/7235/missed-access-to-all-my-repositories-conq) which suggests to run `ssh -v git@bitbucket.org` but I don't how to interpret the output of that. Here it is:

```
stefan@stefan-Desktop:~/Desktop/jobsrc$ ssh -v git@bitbucket.org                          
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/stefan/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/stefan/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/stefan/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/stefan/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/stefan/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/stefan/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/stefan/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/stefan/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.311-c6337e4 app-126
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.311-c6337e4 app-126
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/stefan/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/stefan/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([104.192.143.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = bg_BG.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = bg_BG.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = bg_BG.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = bg_BG.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = bg_BG.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = bg_BG.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = bg_BG.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = bg_BG.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = bg_BG.UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
authenticated via a deploy key.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.

This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:

stremio/qca9377: stefan@desktop -- stefan@stefan-Desktop
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
Transferred: sent 3508, received 1964 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 13117.0, received 7343.7
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Later, I learned that apparently I can't have a key both as an account key and as a repo-specific deployment key. I did have my pubkey assigned as a deployment key on 1 repo from our company. I asked the admin of that repo to remove my key from there, and now I'm getting a different error:

```
stefan@stefan-Desktop:~/Desktop/jobsrc$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:stremio/wifi-setup.git
Cloning into 'wifi-setup'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - I had visually compared the first 10 or so symbols of the pubkey as shown by `cat` and as shown by bitbucket's web UI; they were the same and I considered that enough. But it turns out that, for whatever reason, my local pubkey had an added `stefan@stefan-Desktop` at the end, while the one registered in bitbucket didn't. I think that was the only difference.